# Assign null if subquery retrieves multiple records. How can it be done?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query. I simplified it for demo purpose. I am using SQL Server - t-sql

```
 Select tm.LocID  = (select  LocID from tblLoc tl
                     where tl.LocID = tm.LodID )
 from tblMain tm
```

if the subquery returns multiple records, I like to assign tm.LocID to null else if there is only 1 record returned then assign it to tm.LocID. I am looking for a simple way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

One way I can see is to have a CASE statement and check if (Count * > 1 ) then assign null else return the value but that would require a select statement within a select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea about using a `case` expression for `count(*)`, but it will not require another subquery:

```
SELECT tm.LocID  = (SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(LocID) END
                     FROM   tblLoc tl
                     WHERE  tl.LocID = tm.LodID )
FROM   tblMain tm
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query above (and many of the other answers here) is a *correlated* subquery which will be very slow since it performs a separate aggregation query on each record. This following will address both your problem and *potentially* perform a bit better since the count happens in a single pass.

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN x.locid IS NOT NULL THEN x.locid
    ELSE NULL
  END 
FROM tblMain m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    locid
  FROM tblLoc 
  GROUP BY locid
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
) x
   ON x.locid = m.locid
;
```

The above is in Postgres syntax (what I'm familiar with) so you would have to make it TSQL compatible.

Answer (score 0):

or just use a `HAVING` clause, like

```
Select tm.LocID  = (select  LocID from tblLoc tl
                    where tl.LocID = tm.LodID
                     group by locID
                     having count(*) = 1)
 )
 from tblMain tm
```